# Is it possible to change the exams result to a different scale?

Tags: r, r-exams

We created an exam with a total of 29 points. However, we would like to present to students the HTML using a 0 to 20 scale (`Points` row of the HTML; with the `nops_eval` function):

[image]

The corresponding points of each exercise (summing a total of 29) should continue appearing in the Evaluation grid, e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the points and evaluation for the exercises as it was and just changing the scaling of the sum of the points is not possible. If you want to do so for the HTML reports, I guess it is easiest to read the individual .html files into R, replace the points with what you want to put there. `readLines()`, `gsub()`, and `writeLines()` should be useful here.

However, what is possible, is to change the points associated with each exercise in the entire evaluation. To do so you can use

```
nops_eval(..., points = ...)
```

where `points` must be a vector of the same length as the number of exercises (22 in your case). This overrules the number of points that was previously set within the exercises (via `expoints`) or in `exams2nops(..., points = ...)`.

Comment: However, can we change all the expoints to the new scale? 

(old_expoints x 20)/29 and then can we feed nops_eval with that vector?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I've adapted my response correspondingly.